# I can receive any email sent to my domain, apart from ones addressed to "postmaster" - how can I fix this?

Tags: gmail, g-suite

I let gmail handle all of my emails at mydomain.com.  My main account is webmaster@mydomain.com, but anything works.  dave@mydomain.com, bob@mydomain.com asijsijsisj@mydomain.com - they all come through to my webmaster@mydomain.com email account.

But postmaster@mydomain.com doesn't.

What do I need to change, where?  I've been looking in the domain management google console but can't find anything relevant in there and don't know where else to look!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  You have to add groups in g-suite called "abuse" and "postmaster", with the relevant abuse@ and postmaster@ email addresses.

You then add the user you want to use to those groups, and then that user will receive those emails in addition to whatever they received before.